# Difficult interpreting Real Analysis question

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry the vague title. I really have no idea how to classify this question. Could I get some help interrupting what the question is asking me to prove and hints how to solve?

Suppose that $f:R^n\to R$ is continuous. If there are $x\in R^n$ and $C\in R$ such that $f(x)<C$, then prove that there is $r>0$ such that for all $y\in B_r(x), f(y)<C$

I truly have absolutely no idea what this question is asking me to do.

Comment: Did you mean $C \in \mathbb R$ instead of $C \in \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Hint: let $\epsilon = (C - f(x)) / 2$. Then because $f$ is continuous, there is an $r > 0$ such that...?

Comment: The question is asking to prove that for any continuous function $f(..)$ with $f(x) \lt C$, there is a ball of radius r around $x$ such that $f(y)\lt C$ for all $y$ in the ball.

Comment: If you are standing in hilly but continuously varying terrain, and your altitude is strictly less than 100m, then provided you stay close enough to where you are, as seen from above, then your altitude may change, but will remain strictly less than 100m.

Comment: So we are to prove $f:R^n\to R$ is continuous by proving that both $x$ and $y$ exist within the same finite ball? Also, what exactly is meant by $R^n\to R$? What is the difference between $R^n$ and $R$?

Comment: The notation $f:X\to Y$ means that $f$ is a function from the set $X$ to the set $Y$. The set of all real numbers (or the 1-dimensional line) is $\mathbb R$, and the set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers (or $n$-dimensional space) is $\mathbb R^n$. You're supposed to know these things already if you're being asked this question!

Comment: You'd be surprised how many professors assume knowledge and never bother to explain the most basics definitions of each symbol in proofs. "Introduction to concepts in proofing" is a course that rarely exists but should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity tells us that if you barely move around a point then the function doesn't change that much. The function at a point less than C is telling you that there is some "space" between $f(x)$ and C, there is in fact $\alpha: \quad f(x)<\alpha<C$.
Then provided you stay close enough to x, the function doesn't vary that much and is still below C.
Formally, given $\varepsilon =\frac{C-f(x)}{2}$.
By continuity, $\exists \ r>0: ||x-y||<r \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$.
$$f(y)<\varepsilon+f(x) \leq \frac{C-f(x)}{2}+f(x) < C \quad \quad \forall \ y\in B_r(x)$$

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that $\forall \ y\in B_r(x)$? What part of your inequality shows that $y$ is in the ball of $x$?

Comment: It's not a conclusion, although it appears at the end of the statement. It's a *quantifier*.

Comment: Okay. Then what part of his proof can be used to show that $y\in B_r(x)$?

Comment: @Dylan It's simply true for any $y \in B_r(x)$, where we define that radius to be the one required to have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. We have specified an $\epsilon$, and by one definition of continuity, there then exists a radius that satisfies the second to last line.